# Jquery chosen plugin works in one page but not in another one

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

Hi I have used chosen in other projects before and I havent had any problems with it but now in my current project I can't get it to work on a specific page, although it works on another page.

```
Firebug gives me the error:
 SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
 '!doctype html'
 chosen.jquery.js (row 1)

 SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

'!doctype html'

 prism.js (row 1)

 TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function

$(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
```

The site I develop is using a MVC framework and the view that display/loads the script, the one that doesnt work, looks like this (edit-question):

```html
<h1><?=$title?></h1>
<form method='post'>
    <fieldset>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?=$id?>' required/>
        <input id='textField' type='text' name='titel' placeholder='Titel' value='<?=$titel?>' tabindex='1' required/>
        <textarea id='askQuestion' name='text' placeholder='Fråga' tabindex='2' required/><?=$text?></textarea>
        <select name='tags[]' data-placeholder='Välj taggar, minst 1 - högst 5' class='chosen-select-deselect' tabindex='2'  multiple >
            <option value=''></option>
            <?php
                foreach($tags as $tag){
                $selected="";
                foreach($selectedTags as $selectedTag){
                    if($tag->name == $selectedTag){
                        $selected = "selected";
                    }
                }
                    echo "<option value='$tag->id' $selected >{$tag->name}</option>";
                }
             ?>

       </select>
        <input class='newTags' type='text' name='newTags' placeholder='Ange ny tagg/taggar "taggnamn, taggnamn"'/>
    <input type='submit' name='editQuestion' value='Uppdatera'>
    </fieldset>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='js/chosen_v1.4.1/chosen.jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='js/chosen_v1.4.1/docsupport/prism.js' type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var config = {
      '.chosen-select'           : {},
      '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true, width:'100%', max_selected_options:5},
      '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:'95%'}
    }

    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
    </script>
</form>
```

The view that work (ask-question):

```html
<h1><?=$title?></h1>
<form method='post'>
    <fieldset>
        <input id='textField' type='text' name='titel' placeholder='Titel' tabindex='1' title='Ange en titel på frågan' required/>
        <textarea id='askQuestion' name='text' placeholder='Fråga' tabindex='2' title='Ange frågan' required/></textarea>
        <select name='tags[]' data-placeholder='Välj taggar, minst 1 - högst 5' class='chosen-select-deselect' tabindex='3' multiple >
            <option value=''></option>
            <?php foreach($tags as $tag) : ?>
                <option value='<?=$tag->id?>'><?=$tag->name?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <input class='newTags' type='text' name='newTags' placeholder='Ange ny tagg/taggar "taggnamn, taggnamn"'/>
    <input type='submit' name='createQuestion' value='Skapa'>
    </fieldset>


    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='js/chosen_v1.4.1/chosen.jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='js/chosen_v1.4.1/docsupport/prism.js' type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var config = {
      '.chosen-select'           : {},
      '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true, width:'100%', max_selected_options:5},
      '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:'95%'}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
    </script>
</form>
```

Both views, when displayed, have the same file path and the only thing I can think of that differentiate the two views/pages is that the one that doesnt work(edit-question) have a different url, webroot/questions/edit-question/3/3/8, while the other one, ask-question, have webroot/ask-question. Furthermore, edit-question is populateing the html input elements with values.

I'am not very versed with jquery/javascript so any help is much appriciated!

/ph

Comment: Your JS file includes are all relative paths. That means relative to the page they are loaded from. As you mention your paths are of different depths, it will not find them. Try using absolute paths for now e.g. `<script src='/js/chosen_v1.4.1/chosen.jquery.js'` etc

Comment: I can't get that to work either.. same response. Thank you for your comment tho!